# Is it possible to move and slide table row to the left?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML table and I want to move animate a paging action. For example, each page loads up 3 table rows which are supposed to replace the current onscreen table rows. I'd like to animate that so that the first 3 rows slide out to the left, and the next 3 ones slide in from the right.

I can't seem to come up with a solution using HTML table tag, but I'd like to avoid styled lists or divs if possible.

Here's an example, the **active** class should be visible on first page, when you click the next button, first three rows should slide out to the left, and second three should slide in from the right. https://jsfiddle.net/ba0aLker/

```
<table>
  <tr class="active">
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="active">
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="active">
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>five</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: you should paste the code that you did trying to get the result

Comment: yes it is possible, do you have some code where you want to implement the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a dirty and quick aproximation. You have to tweak it a bit but I think that is a good start point.

First, you need to have the tables on the HTML, and have one with the `active` class. This one is the visible. To the other tables, set `display:none` for them to be hidden.

Then, in the JS, I just change the class `active` to next element. I added an `if` to check that next element is a table, if it isn't then the first table gets the `active` class.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  $("#the_button").click(function() {
var next = $(".tables.active").last().next();

if (next.get(0).tagName != 'TABLE') {
  next = $(".tables").eq(0)
}

$(".tables.active").removeClass("active");
next.addClass("active");
next.next().addClass("active");
next.next().next().addClass("active");


$(".tables").fadeOut(300);
$(".tables.active").delay(300).fadeIn(300);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tables active">
  <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tables active">
  <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tables active">
  <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="tables" style="display:none">
  <tr>
<th>Foo</th>
<th>BAR</th>
<th>FooBar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>bar</td>
<td>foobar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>var</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foovar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tables" style="display:none">
  <tr>
<th>Foo</th>
<th>BAR</th>
<th>FooBar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>bar</td>
<td>foobar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>var</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foovar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tables" style="display:none">
  <tr>
<th>Foo</th>
<th>BAR</th>
<th>FooBar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>bar</td>
<td>foobar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>var</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foovar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="the_button">
  next table
</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort! Unfortunately, I need a solution where I have a single table and page through sets of table rows, eg 3 by 3 rows.